# How to determine if MySQL install is Community or Enterprise without root password?

Tags: mysql, linux, terminal, redhat

I have taken over a production Linux RHEL server which has a MySQL install on it. I need to find out which version of MySql is installed.

Apparently this is easy information to determine which it says [here on mysql.com](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/installation-version.html) but unfortunately no one can remember the root password and no one knows what version of MySQL it is.

I am assuming it is Enterprise but I need to know for sure.

I tried 2 different commands:

```
mysql --version
```

Output:

```
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.6.13, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper
```

and

```
file /usr/sbin/mysqld
```

Output:

```
/usr/sbin/mysqld: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (GNU/Linux), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.18, not stripped
```

Both of these commands provided me with useful information but I still need to figure out if the server has the Community or Enterprise edition.

Comment: Try an `rpm -qa |grep -i mysql` and look at the RPM package names

Comment: Thanks @nos, I tried that but it didn't return any info regarding whether the packages were Community or Enterprise.

Answer (score 0):

No , you can't. You need to login to mysql to get this info.

Can use commands like,

SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "%version%";

Answer (score 0):

You can get the details using `status` command in the mysql command prompt. Don't use the windows cmd prompt to execute the command.

`mysql > Status`